# Having some trouble figuring out where should the form action of my search form lead

Tags: php, laravel

Currently I'm trying to implement search functionality but hit a little roadblock at the moment.

The way I want it to work is this:

- User types a word in the search form located in the navigation bar.
- User is sent to a URL with slug which displays all the results based on the slug

I've already figured the logic on how to retrieve the images based on the slug word, however, I haven't figured out how to pass the slug word from the search bar to the search() function which I would then send me to the search view. I'm not sure if I need a second POST route which I can use in the HTML form form action.

```
public function search($query){
    $images = Image::where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
    ->orWhereHas('tags', function($q) use ($query) {
        return $q->where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
    })->orWhereHas('category', function($q) use ($query) {
        return $q->where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
    })->latest()->get();

    return view('search', ['images' => $images]);
}
```

This is my route so far:

```
Route::get('/search/{query}', 'PagesController@search')->name('searchView');
```

HTML Form:

```
<form action="" method='POST'>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search">
</form>
```

Comment: Try using javascript to grab the text in the search bar and then submit the whole thing using javascript (or jQuery) and include that value as a post item in the data stream.

Comment: your route is get. why are you making a post form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to use the query string. i.e:

**Form:**

```
<form action="{{route('searchView')}}">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search">
</form>
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/search', 'PagesController@search')->name('searchView');
```

**Method:**

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $query = $request->search;
    $images = Image::where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
    ->orWhereHas('tags', function($q) use ($query) {
        return $q->where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
    })->orWhereHas('category', function($q) use ($query) {
        return $q->where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
    })->latest()->get();

    return view('search', ['images' => $images]);
}
```

The route will look like

```
/search?search=queryhere
```

**But**

if you want to the route to be something like `/search/query` you need to call the route. This is not normal behavior of html from. so you would need to make the request using some js script.

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); search();">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="searchQuery" id="searchQuery">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function search() {
        var query = document.getElementById('searchQuery').value
        window.location.href='/search/'+query
    }
</script>
```

and keep your route and method as is.